# check a file exists in azure data lake storage gen2 via python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-lake-gen2

Hi i want to know the file existence in ADLS Gen 2

```
file_client = service_client.get_file_client(file_system='filelayer', file_path='my_file.txt')
```

This gives the file_client, but how to check if the file exists there because am trying to rename it and gives error as(if not exists):

```
(SourcePathNotFound) The source path for a rename operation does not exist
```

so i want to do the rename `file_client.rename_file(target_name)` only if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file_exists, but you could use get_file_properties()

```py
def exists(file_client: DataLakeFileClient):
    try:
        file_client.get_file_properties()
        return True
    except ResourceNotFoundError:
        return False

file_client = service_client.get_file_client(file_system='filelayer', file_path='my_file.txt')  
if exists(file_client):
   file_client.rename_file(targetName)
```

However, some people (including me) considered the pythonic way to to solve the problem doing a try/catch directly:

```py
file_client = service_client.get_file_client(file_system='filelayer', file_path='my_file.txt')

try: 
   file_client.rename(target_name)
except ResourceNotFoundError: 
   # log that the files does not exist or not, up to you
   pass
``
```

Comment: FYI: You need to import the error manually for your function to work: `from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError`

Answer (score -1):

Isn't try/except enough for your needs?
You can put get_file_client in try and if not found you will catch SourcePathNotFound exception.